# C# equivalent of 64-bit unsigned long long in C++

Tags: c#, c++, long-integer, unsigned, ulong

I am building a DLL which will be used by C++ using COM.
Please let me know what would be the C# equivalent of C++ 64-bit `unsigned long long`.

Will it be ulong type in C# ?
Please confirm.

Thanks,
Gagan

Comment: `ulong` is a [64-bit unsigned long int](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t98873t4.aspx).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Maybe this will help you:

- [`ulong`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t98873t4.aspx) (64-bit unsigned integer)
- [`double`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/678hzkk9.aspx)(64-bit floating-point number).

Comment: is that guaranteed for all time (like Java long type will always be 64 bit)?

Comment: Huh? In C#, `ulong` is short for System.UInt64 which is (and always will be) a 64-bit unsigned integer.

Comment: @dtb: have you ever seen any official documentation with such guarantee about C# shorts?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ya5y69ds.aspx http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exx3b86w.aspx http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms228593.aspx

Answer (score 3):

For anything that goes beyond `ulong`, you might as well use the C# [`BigInteger` Structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Finding factorial of numbers > 20 is not possible without `BigInteger` data type. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: not true anymore. Since .NET Core 7.0 you there are [System.Int128](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int128?view=net-7.0) and [System.UInt128](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uint128?view=net-7.0) that's wider than `ulong`

Answer (score 1):

In C++, the size of integer types varies depending on whether the program is running on a 32- or 64-bit machine, whereas C# integer types are platform-independent. So, they're not interoperable.

Rather, in C# there are the `IntPtr` and `UIntPtr` types, which are intended for P/Invoke, and whose size is 4 bytes on 32-bit machines and 8 bytes on 64-bit machines, which makes them equivalent to the C++ `signed long` and `unsigned long` types, respectively.

Answer (score -7):

Since C++11, you can use these:

- `int8_t`
- `int16_t`
- `int32_t`
- `int64_t`
- `uint8_t`
- `uint16_t`
- `uint32_t`
- `uint64_t`

Their size is guaranteed to remain the same regardless of anything.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer.

Comment: You got the question backwards

Comment: Wrong way round, plus not very specific even if wanting to go into the DLL